# Invalid resource directory name for android dimens

Tags: android

[image]

Hi,I have a dimens resource files with different screen densities,everything worked just fine,I tested it,but suddenly I got an error:

> Error: Invalid resource directory name
>
> res\values-(xxxhdpi): Error: Invalid resource directory name

Any advice and suggestion will be greatly appreciated.Thx.

Comment: Your folder name is `values-(xxxhdpi)`? That's not really valid.

Comment: Okay,so how it should be?It worked for a while,I thought it was ok.

Comment: Switch to `Project view` instead of `Android view` and remove the parenthesis in the folder. It should only be `values-xxxhdpi`.

Comment: @Enzokie thank you very very much,it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to `Project view` instead of `Android view` and remove the parenthesis in the folder. It should only be `values-xxxhdpi`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different values folder for different screens.

[image]

Then, inside the values directory, you have to place your dimens.

[image]

[image]